# 32 bit AMD driver on 64 bit Freya

Tags: graphic-drivers

I'm using the 64 bit ver. of Freya and I have an AMD HD5770. I installed the latest driver provided at AMD website. Now this driver is 64 bit only and 32 bit games don't run. 
I need to know if I can install the 32 bit driver similarly and not break anything. 
I know the repository's proprietary fglrx contains both libraries but I just wanted to use the latest drivers.

Comment: Please elaborate on the issue 32bit games have. Are you using steam? What games are you trying to play? Can you attach logs? Because installing the 32bit version of your driver will most likely _not_ fix this problem (you'll screw up your system).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit technical, so let me know with a comment on anything you get stuck with but here goes:

Your 32 bit games might not be failing because of your driver but because 64 bit Ubuntu doesn't ship 32 bit libraries. there used to be an easy metapackage for 32 bit support called ia32-libs but for whatever reason it was removed.

To work around this go to your game's folder in terminal eg `~/games/foobar` and in it type `ldd foobar` using the output to find the missing libraries. You can then install the 32 bit versions of them. As an example for sdl2 you'd type `libsdl2.0:i386` the `:i386` denoting the architecture. You could theoretically install arm libs this way but they won't run on your processor.

`apt-cache search foo` will probably help you alot here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But it didn't exactly answer my query. Installing from the repository everything works fine as it installs both 32 and 64 bit libs.  I want to know if I can manually install 32 bit and 64 bit drivers individually provided by AMD at its website as the 64 bit AMD driver doesnot install the 32 bit libs. The repository installs an older driver.

Comment: ok. your best bet is rolling back to a known good configuration.

Comment: or you could see if "oibaf" or "xorg edgers" ppas have more up-to-date but still legacy supporting stuff.